# Ignoring Multiple Whitespace Characters in a MongoDB Query

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I have a MongoDB query that searches for addresses. The problem is that if a user accidentally adds an extra whitespace, the query will not find the address. For example, if the user types `123    Fakeville St` instead of `123 Fakeville St`, the query will not return any results.

Is there a simple way to deal with this issue, perhaps using `$regex`? I guess the space would need to be ignore between the house number (123) and the street name (Fakeville). My query is set up like this:

```
@app.route('/getInfo', methods=['GET'])
def getInfo():
    address = request.args.get("a")
    addressCollection = myDB["addresses"]
    addressJSON = []
    regex = "^" + address

    for address in addressCollection.find({'Address': {'$regex':regex,'$options':'i'} },{"Address":1,"_id":0}).limit(3):
        addressJSON.append({"Address":address["Address"]})
    return jsonify(addresses=addressJSON)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up the query before sending it off:

```
>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', '123  abc')
'123 abc'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', '123    abc def   ghi')
'123 abc def ghi'
```

You'll probably want to make sure that the data in your database is similarly normalised. Also consider similar strategies for things like punctuation.

In fact, using a regex for this seems overly strict, as well as reinventing the wheel. Consider using a proper search engine such as Lucene or Elasticsearch.

Comment: Super. Thank you. This works. Will look into Lucene and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach without using regex you could try is to utilise [MongoDB text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes). By adding a text index on the field you can perform text searches using [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator

For example:

```
db.coll.find(
            { $text:{$search:"123 Fakeville St"}},
            { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
       .sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).limit(1)
```

This should work for entries such as: "123    Fakeville St.", "123 fakeville street", etc. As long as the important parts of the address makes it in.

See more info on [$text behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#behavior)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out as well.