# How to ignore string with whitespaces in mongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have `mongoDB` data with zip codes stored different format like -

```
BS2 8BX
BS 28 BX
BS28BX
BS28B X
BS28 BX
B S28BX
```

where input to search criteria is `BS28BX` which should return all above formatted data

Tried with below query which is not showing all above results

```
db.addressBook.find({$or:[ {postCode:{$regex:/BS28BX/}},{postCode:"BS28BX"}]},{postCode:1})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring Multiple Whitespace Characters in a MongoDB Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316869/ignoring-multiple-whitespace-characters-in-a-mongodb-query)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
/B\s*S\s*2\s*8\s*B\s*X\s*/
```

Basically I accept 0 or more white spaces between each char in your query String